# when exactly the increment happens in a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have this logic that ideally should find pairs of ints in an int array, and after finding the pair, remove it from the array itself and start over.

While debugging I noticed something that, for the given sample input test case when `i=0` and `j=3` the `if` condition satisfies and the **1st** `pair` is found then `pairs` value gets incremented and then both values get removed from the array as expected, and `n` decrements to `7` from `9` and then `j` is set to `0`, now, control goes back to the `for` statement and ideally as `j<n` the body of for loop should be executed, but, I see that in my debugger when the `for` statement gets executed, `j` is set to `1`.

I didn't understand this. When exactly is the increment happening here in my `for` loop because if I just set it to `0` and the condition satisfies the control should move on to find the next pair?

```
/*
sample input case
9 (n number of inputs)
10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20 (array of ints)
*/

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (ar[i] == ar[j]) {
            pairs++;
            ar.erase(ar.begin() + i);
            ar.erase(ar.begin() + j-1);
            n-=2;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The increment expression is executed after each iteration of the loop. So that happens right *after* `j = 0;`

Comment: To fix try setting `j = -1` (although I have my doubts about the logic overall).

Comment: `for (a;b;c) d` executes like `{a; while (b) {d; c;}}`

Comment: Iterating on a container that you also modify is very not recommended, also, you want to set `j = i + 1` instead of `j = 1`, and for `i` use `i < n - 1`.

Comment: `sort(begin(ar), end(ar)); ar.erase(unique(begin(ar), end(ar)), end(ar));` Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), this for loop

```
for (init_statement ; condition ; iteration_expression) {
     statement
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
{
    init_statement
    while ( condition ) {
        statement
        iteration_expression ;
    } 
}
```

Your confusion is most likely caused from erasing elements while iterating. Inserting / Removing elements during iteration is not recommended. If you do, you have to take into account that in iteraton `n` the `n-th` element in the container is not necessarily the `n-th` element in the original container. Read about the erase-remove idiom for a less error prone way of erasing elements.